# Error en Spyder: % matplotlib inline ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

soy nuevo programando con python, he estado programando en spyder y el programa me corría bien, hasta hace poco dejó de correr y me marca error en esa línea, si la comento salen mas errores al respecto, sería bien recibida su ayuda

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_files  #Funcion para  cargar DataSet desde el formato que esta 

data = load_files(Dir, encoding="utf-8",decode_error="replace") #https://is.gd/wd1jcP

#Dar numero de categoria
labels, counts = np.unique(data.target,return_counts=True) #Labels es el resultado de la librer[ia numpy que convierte las clasas a numeros

#Se convierten de numeros a los nombres de las clases y se crea un diccionario con la funcion dict, representa el num de articulos
labels_str = np.array(data.target_names)[labels]
print(dict(zip(labels_str, counts)))

#Preparacion de datos vectorizandolos
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_entre, X_prueba, y_entre, y_prueba = train_test_split(data.data, data.target, test_size=0.2,train_size=0.8)
len(X_entre),len(X_prueba)#La func len regresa el numero de datos

print(X_prueba) #Tweets en texto

#Los articulos se convertiran  en palabras y se eliminaran las stopwords(of,on) y apabras como Biggest se contraeran a big
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words="english", max_features=1000) #Se usa las stop words de la libreria sklearn y desppues s e especificia que se tomaran las 1000 palabras mas usadas
vectorizer.fit(X_entre) #Frecuencia de terminos

#Modelo
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
cls = MultinomialNB()
cls.fit(vectorizer.transform(X_entre), y_entre)

#Clasificacion
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
    y_pred = cls.predict(vectorizer.transform(X_prueba))
    print(accuracy_score(y_prueba, y_pred))
    print(classification_report(y_prueba, y_pred))
    print(y_pred)
```

Comment: La primera línea que pone `%matplotlib inline` no es válida en Python (y por tanto tampoco en spyder). Sólo es válida en un Jupyter Notebook debido a que para este framework esa primera línea es un "meta-comando" que le sirve para cargar matplotlib e inicializarlo de modo que las gráficas se vean en el propio notebook. En un script python que se ejecute fuera de Jupyter debes importar e inicializar matplotlib "a mano". Posiblemente baste con eliminar esa línea, ya que lo importas de todas formas más abajo y se inicializará con el _backend_ por defecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Los demás errores saltaron por espacios inesperados, de verdad muchas gracias :)